# process card before sending/saving order details to customer in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, wordpress-plugin-creation

i have an API of payment gateway. i have done everything.

1. i have defined a form to get visa/master-card/american-express card details.

   ```
   public function payment_fields() {

               // I will echo() the form, but you can close PHP tags and print it directly in HTML
               echo '<fieldset id="wc-' . esc_attr( $this->id ) . '-cc-form" class="wc-credit-card-form wc-payment-form" style="background:transparent;">';

               // Add this action hook if you want your custom payment gateway to support it
               do_action( 'woocommerce_credit_card_form_start', $this->id );

               // I recommend to use inique IDs, because other gateways could already use #ccNo, #expdate, #cvc
               echo '
                   <div class="form-row form-row-wide">
                       <label>Brand<span class="required">*</span></label>
                       <select id="datafast_brand" name="datafast_brand">
                           <option>American Express</option>
                           <option selected>Visa</option>
                           <option>Mastercard</option>
                       </select>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-row form-row-first">
                       <label>Card Number <span class="required">*</span></label>
                       <input id="datafast_cardnumber" name="datafast_cardnumber" value="4263982640269299" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Car Number">
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-row form-row-last">
                       <label>Card Holder <span class="required">*</span></label>
                       <input id="datafast_cardholder" value="tazeem" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Card Holder">
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-row form-row-first">
                       <label>Expiry Date <span class="required">*</span></label>
                       <input id="datafast_expdate" value="02/23" name="datafast_expdate" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="MM / YY">
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-row form-row-last">
                       <label>Card Code (CVC) <span class="required">*</span></label>
                       <input id="datafast_cvv" name="datafast_cvv" value="837" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="CVC">
                   </div>
                   <div class="clear"></div>';

               do_action( 'woocommerce_credit_card_form_end', $this->id );

               echo '<div class="clear"></div></fieldset>';

           }
   ```
2. now i want when click on "place order" button information of above define card will be get and display here in this below function to process card. Before, information of order to save in database and send email to customer.

   ```
   public function payment_fields() {

               public function process_payment( $order_id ) {

               global $woocommerce;

               // we need it to get any order detailes
               $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

                           **// here i want to show/get details of above card details. to process card before order submission.**


                       // we received the payment
                       $order->payment_complete();
                       $order->reduce_order_stock();

                       // some notes to customer (replace true with false to make it private)
                       $order->add_order_note( 'Hey, your order is processed by DATAFAST payment gateway. Kindly confirm payment then release Order! Thank you!', true );

                       // Empty cart
                       $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

                       // Redirect to the thank you page
                       return array(
                           'result' => 'success',
                           'redirect' => $this->get_return_url( $order )
                       );


           }
   ```

Comment: so, what's preventing you from doing what you want?

Comment: i want to get credit-card form data in process_payment( $order_id ) {} function then in this method i will process this card.